# I want actions not views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost

Rails is doing my head in.

I'm trying now to put something together to pull screen scraped data from site X through to client Y via a ruby script on server Z

I don't want views, I just want the request to look like `domain.com/action/method`

Inside `routes.rb` I have:

`match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'`

But it still won't work. I just get `ActionView::MissingTemplate` in the log.

**Achtung!**

If I deliberately put a faulty method in that subsequently calls `render` - the log file indicates the method executed badly, so I don't think it's something wrong with the "action" controller.

**Update**

Dreamhost's configuration needed me to specify ':layout => false'

Comment: Actions _are_ methods, not sure what is `/action/method` supposed to refer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what do you want the app to respond with, if not something from a view? You can manually respond with a string like so:

```
def index
  render :text => "Hi from the #{controller_name} controller!"
end
```

Comment: Yeah that usually works, but for whatever reason it doesn't on dreamhost?! Meh.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to render anything do this:

```
render :nothing => true
```

It sends a 200 OK response.  Read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-nothing